# Return Subflow to parent

Tags: twilio

How can I return from subflow to parent using split based on?

[image]

TY

Twilio Studio > Flows

..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "returning"? The screenshot suggests, you want to have a transition to a previous widget. Returning to a subflow, would actually mean to go go back to a "Run Subflow" widget that is not shown in the screenshot

Comment: Hello @IObert. My Main Flow call one subflow and I have one option in subflow to return to Main Flow. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The return from the subflow to the parent flow happens automatically when the subflow terminates (i.e. a widget doesn't have an outgoing transition.

This is how you can continue in the parent flow
[image: parent flow]

And this shows how you can end a subflow
[image: subflow]